# Insert values one by one into the search field and at the same time show images one by one with the same button?

Tags: javascript, html

With this code we can insert one by one 4 different text values into the search field ('Decoration', 'Health', 'Fun', 'Yesterday 4').

But I need to simultaneously insert an image for each of those text values (appearing logically outside the search field). Note that the next image should appear in place of the first and delete this one.

See in: http://jsfiddle.net/7bpaL5hy/

```js
   
const myValues = ['Decoration', 'Health', 'Fun', 'Yesterday 4'];
let myInd = 0;

function setValue() {
    document.getElementById('bbb').value = myValues[myInd];
    myInd = myInd >= (myValues.length - 1) ? 0 : myInd+1;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="set_Value" id="set_Value" value="submit" onclick="setValue()" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="bbb" id="bbb" />
        </label>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Why not add just an array of images? So you have myValues and myImages.

Comment: I've been trying with fuction} else ... but I still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the image tag and a list of images as an arrangement, please take a look at the following example

```js
let init = 0;
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const img = document.querySelector("img");
const myValues = [
  {
    value: "Item 1",
    image: "item-1.png",
  },
  {
    value: "Item 2",
    image: "item-2.png",
  },
  {
    value: "Item 3",
    image: "item-3.png",
  },
  {
    value: "Item 4",
    image: "item-4.png",
  },
];

document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", submitHandler);

function submitHandler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const { value, image } = getCurrentValue();

  input.value = value;
  img.src = image;
  img.alt = value;

  updateInit();
}

function getCurrentValue() {
  return myValues[init];
}

function updateInit() {
  if (init < myValues.length - 1) {
    init += 1;
  } else {
    init = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="" alt="" />
<form>
  <input />
  <button type="submit">Click</button>
</form>
```

A convenient way to relate values to their respective image is for both values to be properties of an object, so I changed myValues to an array of objects.

You will notice that only the value of the alt attribute is shown since there is no link with a real image. It still helps to demonstrate how it works.